# How to validate columns of csv file and show failed rows in a table using c#

Tags: c#

I have CSV file which contains around 25 columns and 100 rows.

I am trying validate each and every column of a row and if it fails, I want to create a table with row number, failed column name etc and show it once all rows get processed.

Any leads on this can be done? How can I achieve this?
below is the Code:

```
  protected void ValidateData_Click(object sender , EventArgs e )
        {
            //Upload and save the file
            string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(UploadFile.PostedFile.FileName);
            UploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);

            //read and validate csv file
            ValidateCsv(filePath);

        }
        //Validate CSV file
        private void ValidateCsv(string fileContent)
        {
            DataTable getCSVData;
            getCSVData=GetData(fileContent);
            ValidateRows(getCSVData);    

        }

        //get data from csv
        private DataTable GetData(string fileContent)
        {
            //read csv file
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileContent))
            {
                string[] headers = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                foreach (string header in headers)
                {
                    dataTable.Columns.Add(header);
                }
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] csvRow = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        dataRow[i] = csvRow[i];
                    }
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                }

            }
            return dataTable;
        }
        //validate Rows
        private void ValidateRows(DataTable csvDataTable)
        {

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: This should be a fairly simple thing to accomplish overall. What have you tried so far? I'd be happy to help with any specific issues you run into but this isn't a place for someone to do all the leg work for you. Try a few approaches and then come back when you run into any issues with specific code.

Comment: @JoshuaHysong , sorry i am new to c#,i have tried so far is to get the data from csv to Datatable and then going through  each row and each column, but i am not confused on the validation part where i need to store the failed field and row number

Comment: Can you amend your question to show the code you are using so far?

Comment: just added as answer, as i am not able to edit it.

Comment: Do you just need to know how to loop over the datatable in the validation method?

Comment: @JoshuaHysong actually i trying to validate each column of a row against specific rules like id column should not null , and if csv has some invalid fields , i want to show them in table .

Comment: Ok, so one approach then would be to loop over the rows in the datatable and check that row against your various rules. If the row fails the checks then add it to another datable which will, after the loop is done, be shown in another form. I can post some code for a rough structure of this as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: @JoshuaHysong looks good,it would be great if you post the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a super basic structure you could use for your validation method.

```
private void ValidateRows(DataTable csvDataTable)
{
    DataTable invalidatedTable = new DataTable();

    // If you only want certain columns in the datatable do this for each.
    DataTable invalidatedTable = new DataTable();
    invalidatedTable.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(string));

    // If you want all the columns in the new datatable that are in the source then do this.
    DataTable invalidatedTable = csvDataTable.Clone();

    // Loop over all the rows in the datatable
    foreach (DataRow row in csvDataTable.Rows)
    {
        bool invalidated = false;

        // Check if id column is null
        if (row["id"] == null)
            invalidated = true;

        // Check some other column is not equal to some value
        if (row["columnName"].ToString() != "Whatever you consider valid")
        {
            invalidated = true;
        }

        // If you'd like to loop through the columns instead...
        foreach (DataColumn column in csvDataTable.Columns)
        {
            if (row[column] != SomeTest)
            {
                invalidated = true;
            }
        }

        // if any of the rules above marked this row as invalid then add to table
        if (invalidated)
        {           
            // this will add a copy of the entire row from the original table
            invalidatedTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);

            // if instead you'd like to edit the data first then do this
            // Note: Depending on your data structure you may need to add nulls or values
            // to columns to keep your tables with the same structure.
            DataRow invalidRow = invalidatedTable.NewRow()
            invalidRow["columnName"] = "someValue"
            invalidatedTable.Rows.Add(invalidRow);
        }

    } // End Loop

    // Show the invalid rows on a form control
    SomeFunctionThatBindsDatatableToFormControl(invalidatedTable);
}
```

Depending on your specific needs there are many ways this could be modified, improved, etc but hopefully this can get you started at least.

Comment: i think we need to traverse through column of each row as its not able to find  the row["id"]

Comment: I've edited above to show looping through columns as well. I used "id" just as a placeholder. That string would need to exactly match the column name of the column you are wanting to check in that instance.

Comment: thanks a lot Joshua, its working now.i was trying to add only columns of a row which are invalid into invalidatedTable.As the above code is just adding a new row.any idea on this?

Comment: You could just add null for the columns that are valid into that row.

Comment: ok but how the invalidatedTable get a failed row as there is no assignment is happning from csvDataTable. i just tried various ways but failed.

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to assign a null row. Make sure the code does not try to assign anything to a row if there is no need to.

Comment: No, i have failed Row however not able to see that Row in invalidatedTable.So just trying how that row will be added.as this code    if (invalidated)
        {
            DataRow invalidRow = invalidatedTable.NewRow();
            invalidatedTable.Rows.Add(invalidRow);
        }  is not working.

Comment: Whoops! That was a mistake on my part. It was creating a row and then trying to immediately assign that blank created row. I've edited the answer above.

Comment: yep :) but now throwing this error message: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

Comment: You'll need to model out the comments in the new table manually or clone the structure of the old table. Answer has been edited.

Comment: i have tried the above however same error at   invalidatedTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray); Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

Comment: To use itemArray the destination table schema needs to match the source table schema. In that case you'll want to clone the original table into the new one. Use the debugger to step through the code and make sure the new datatable object has the same columns as the source.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: yep it helped a lot :) I am trying a mechanism where i can validate  columns efficient way.as there are 25 columns ,so i dont think putting 25 condition will be good option.case is one alternative and anything else you can suggest?